# Swap the class names of draggable with droppable on drop using jquery drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have table and using jquery drag and drop to exchange values of each td with other. I did this using the following:

```
        $("#a tr td").draggable({
            appendTo: "body",
            helper: 'clone',
            cursor: "move",
            revert: "invalid"
        });


        $('#a tr td').droppable({
           accept: function(ui, item) {
           if($(this).html().trim().length != 0)
              return false;
       },

           drop:function (event, ui ) {
             $(this).append(ui.draggable.text());
             var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("class");
             var droppableId = $(this).attr("class");
         $( "ui.draggable" ).switchClass( "draggableId", " droppableId");
        //$(this).switchClass( "droppableId", "draggableId");
             $(ui.draggable).empty();

       }
       });  `
```

But from above i can swap only values associated with the td, But i want the class name associated with TD elements to change. I tried switchClass but no luck. Please suggest me method to achive this.

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/ggbhat/BLJFp/3/

In fiddle you can see number can be swapped, i want background color also changed(by swapping class name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your drop function you can swap the class attributes like this:

```
drop: function (event, ui)
{
    var draggable      = $(ui.draggable)
      , droppable      = $(this)
      , draggableClass = draggable.attr('class')
      , droppableClass = droppable.attr('class');

    droppable.append(draggable.text());
    draggable.attr('class', droppableClass);
    droppable.attr('class', draggableClass);
    draggable.empty();
}
```

Check out the updated [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BLJFp/6/).

Comment: I want class name to be changed for both draggable and droppable. If draggable as class name "A" and droppable as class name"B", then it should changed to draggable class name "B" and droppable  class name"A". In my scenario i need background color to change.

Comment: @ggbhat I have updated my answer to show you an example of how that could be done.